# CKEditor Strips Styles When Editing Link

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg

By changing the `href` via right-clicking a link and choosing to "Edit Link" in CKEditor, all of the inline styles in the `<a>` tag are stripped.

I have already set `allowedContent: true` in config.js to no avail.

How do I configure CKEditor to avoid stripping these styles after changing the link URL?

Edit: Before changing the link I could have:

`<a href="http://test.com" style="color:333333;">test</a>`

And after changing the link target it becomes:

`<a href="http://foo.bar">test</a>`

Comment: WFM. I checked it [here](http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.7/standard/samples/plugins/magicline/magicline.html) (this sample has the ACF disabled).

Comment: Did you by chance change the link when editing? I tried that same example, and the "style" attribute in the ```a``` tag was removed.

To reproduce: open sample, choose "Source" in editor 1, add example line 1 to the top of the example, open the preview, right click the link, "Edit Link", save, view source again.

Comment: My fault. I have missed the first paragraph and thought that it's related to the ACF. I can confirm that the style is gone after using the link dialog. So this is a bug - http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/12931

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! I was frantically looking around trying to find what I missed.

I created the bug report you linked to. Hopefully we can get a resolution!